# C# - Override OnFileActivated - No Suitable Method

Tags: c#, uwp, overriding

When following the example [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-file-activation)

This code throws an error:

```
protected override void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs args)
{
       // TODO: Handle file activation
       // The number of files received is args.Files.Size
       // The name of the first file is args.Files[0].Name
}
```

The error is:

```
'MainPage.OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs)': no suitable method found to override
```

Why is this override method not found? I am using UWP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you look at the documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.onfileactivated?view=winrt-19041

you will see the override should be on the application class, you haven't provided the code, but it looks like you have tried to overload it on a page.